# Magento checkout stuck with Submitting Order Information

Tags: magento-1.8, onepage-checkout

Magento checkout stuck with “Submitting Order Information”

Magento Version Magento ver. 1.8.0.1 http://test.cmedical.nl

The entire process works in the checkout (Billing info, shipping info, shipping method, etc.) except when one finally decides to submit the order, (hit "place order” button) it just hangs at "submitting order information”. After sitting there for a few minutes, the shopper will be returned to the shopping cart, and the order never makes it through!

I hope and assume others have had the same problem? Have you been able to fix it? I’m worried that it might be the theme because I’ve haven’t had much luck finding the solution on the internet. However, I don’t understand where the images & css of the custom theme would interfere with the order process.

I’ve tried multiply solutions but none worked.
It seems i get a prototype.js 302 moved error if i use crome + f12

Has anyone had experience in the one page checkout process? If I could get any input, I would really appreciate it. I’m about to pull my hair out.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below solution make sure to take backup of org files:

Resolution, replaced all files in /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout with a backup copy. This sometimes will fix it.

If not, then comment line 208 (or 290 in 1.9.1.0) in Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::successAction:

```
public function successAction()
{
    $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
    if (!$session->getLastSuccessQuoteId()) {
        // $this->_redirect('checkout/cart'); //comment this line 
        // return; //you can comment this also
    }

    $lastQuoteId = $session->getLastQuoteId();
    $lastOrderId = $session->getLastOrderId();
    $lastRecurringProfiles = $session->getLastRecurringProfileIds();
    if (!$lastQuoteId || (!$lastOrderId && empty($lastRecurringProfiles))) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }

    $session->clear();
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action');
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Then do another checkout, and usually the success page is displayed. Now here is the strange part, remove the comment line 208 and 209 so it is back to the original. Do another checkout, what happen? The success page remains as it should be.